# TestNG report: The stacktrace shows the method where a failure occurred, but does not show the line number

Tags: report, testng

I'm running TestNG, and the end report shows a failure, and then a stacktrace of the failure. However, at the point of the stack trace that covers my test method, it says "(Unknown Source)" instead of a line number.

A line number would make things a lot easier!

Is there a config option I missed? How do I get it to print out the line number too?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening either because this section of the code was optimized by the JIT or you didn't compile it with `-g` (or `debug` in ant).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! Now I see this in ant, separate from testng. So, javac default looks like -g:lines,source whereas ant's default is -g:none. Do you have any idea why ant is set that way?

Comment: Ok, so I added debuglevel="line,source" to my javac target in ant. Now the TestNG does not show "Unknown Source", but it still does not give me a line number. Is there anything else I need to do to make the line number show up? It would be very useful in tracking down errors.